# Looping through excel rows keeps given me an ArrayIndex...Exception

Tags: java, excel, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Okay so I am stuck and I am sure it is a simple solution.  Basically I am beginning my initial conversion, or at least constructing a demo, to a keyword driven framework for selenium testing.  Each row will contain data that will be used to drive the test. After the row is complete, the next row will contain the next test and so on. So I just started and I am having a little bit of trouble.  Here is my code:

```
public List<String> getRowData(String row){
    Sheet sheet = null;
    List<String> getContents = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        sheet = getWorkBook().getSheet("test");
        for(int i=0; i<sheet.getRow(i).length; i++){
            getRowData = sheet.getRow(i);
            for(Cell rowData : getRowData){
                System.out.print(String.format("Row info: %s\n", rowData.getContents()));
                getContents.add(rowData.getContents());
            }
        }
    }catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("This is an exception!");
    } catch (NullPointerException np){
        System.out.print("File does not exist!");
    }return getContents;
}
```

The strings for the exceptions are just placeholders, not going to be final. But I am getting an ArrayIndex....Exception.  I do understand a little why I am getting the error, but I am trying to obviously break out of the loop once the row or row content is empty.  I implemented a condition such that

```
if(sheet.getRow(i) == null){
                break;
            }
```

But it still evaluated and provides the same exception.  I am stuck and would like your help in trying to break out of the loop when there are no contents.  Thank you

Comment: The NullPointer I had added that in there but should not be.  I will add an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds (Catch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `for(int i=0; i<sheet.getRow(i).length; i++)`

to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++){
    if(sheet.getRow(i) == null) break;

    //rest of the code
}
```

But are you sure you want to break the loop on an empty row and not continue to the next row?

Comment: Thank you xgeorgekx.  Well for testing purposes whatever the last row is that has data, that is the last test case within the test set

Comment: yeah but what if there is an empty row in between?

Comment: Ahh I see - and in such case how would you handle that? Say if there are truly no more rows left with info?

Comment: you have the amount of rows as a stop condition for the for loop. So just replace `break;` with `continue;`. This way you will check every line till the end of the file. If empty you skip to next etc.